# A Problem by I. N. Herstein (in Monthly)

Tags: group-theory

Herstein had posed following problem in [American Mathematical Monthly](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322366?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents):

> [image]
>   [image]

*Many people answered it* and some people solved it for *finite* simple groups.

If a problem can be solved in different ways, it is certainly interesting (for me at least). I want to see the *different ways to prove this*.

If one knows any other solution, please give me a *hint*.

(I would appreciate small Hint, rather than complete solution. You may post it in "Solution".)

Comment: The first link is broken for me, and the second behind a paywall.