# An exciting question about automorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I have encounter a question related to automorphism and I found it is really interesting. Unfortunately I cannot completely solve this question.

Question: Suppose that $G$ is a simple nonabelian group. Prove that if $f$ is an automorphism of $G$ such that
$x f(x) = f(x) x$ for every $x \in G$ ( i.e. $x$ commute with $f(x)$ ), then $f = 1$ ( the identity automorphism).

Outline of my idea: Let $S = \{a \in G, a^{-1}f(a)\}$ be the group generated by those elements of the form $g^{-1}f(g)$ where $g \in G$, I intend to show that $S$ is a normal subgroup.

For any $b \in G$, let $b = f(c)$ for some $c \in G$. Now:
$$
b^{-1}a^{-1}f(a)b = b^{-1}a^{-1}f(ac) = (ab)^{-1}f(ac) = (acc^{-1}f(c))^{-1}f(ac) = 
$$
$$
[(c^{-1}f(c))^{-1}][(ac)^{-1}f(ac)] \in S
$$
which shows that $S$ is a normal subgroup. As $G$ is simple so we must have $S = 1$  or $S = G$. But I have no idea how to rule out the case for $S = G$.

Anyone can help me or give a more simple way to solve this question. Thanks!

Comment: You say you don't know how to type $g^{-1}$ - perhaps looking at the site faqs would lead you to [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/801393). You should really be using this to format all of your questions here.

Comment: To type the inverse, write g^{-1} inside of dollar signs like $g^{-1}$.

Comment: Is mathjax a software for pc or not? Can I get it for free?

Comment: All you have to do is to type \$g^{-1}\$ - try it!

Comment: mathjax runs on the servers that host stackexchange.  You do not need to install it on your own computer.

Comment: Perhaps we can show that S is a abelian group. Which forces that S =1.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde S is the generating group generated by all the elements $g^{-1}f(g)$ for g ∈ G.

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h222009p1231458) and the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526810/a-problem-by-i-n-herstein-in-monthly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well-known problem by Herstein from $1984$. A solution by Thomas J. Laffey is given here:

[A Problem by I. N. Herstein (in Monthly)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526810/a-problem-by-i-n-herstein-in-monthly)

Comment: I have a question: why the subgroup N in your link is normal?

Comment: Is is the *normal* subgroup generated by $x,\phi(x)$ and not just the subgroup generated by it. So by definition it is normal.

Comment: I don't understand what's your point. You mean N is the normal subgroup with generators x and ϕ(x) right?